# break out of loop and still return value

Tags: recursion, return, break

I'm implementing dijkstras algorithm. After find the shortest path to the end node, the method needs to stop running and return the shortest path that it found. My algorithm is recursive so to function properly, my method needs to break out of the recursion after returning the shortest path. How should I go about doing this? If I need to use an exception, how could I implement it so that it throws after the return statement? If it is relevant, my method needs to return a LinkedList.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow. Why don't you show us what you have tried sofar? Share some of your code.

Comment: Are you sure your recursive algorithm actually implements Dijkstra's algorithm?  A quick google for "Dijkstra's Algorithm recursive" found a post ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/16074164/224132 ) which has a convincing explanation of why Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't lend itself to a recursive implementation: It needs to jump between branches at every iteration.  A recursive implementation is probably trivially tail-recursion or something instead of a loop, passing a data structure by reference.